# Cannot display arduino data into kivy window

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, kivy

Im am trying to display my arduino data into my kivy window under label but it says an error " ValueError: Label.text accept only str". Anyone able to help?
[image: Arduino serial monitor]

Below is my python kivy file

## test.py file

```
import serial
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MainWindow(Screen):
    def tm(self):
        while (1):
            with serial.Serial('COM4', 9600) as ser:
                x = ser.readline()
                return str(x)
                ser.close()

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

hi = Builder.load_file("test.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return hi

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

test.kv file

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:

    Label:
        size: 75, 50
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'bottom': 1}
        background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        text: root.x
```

Answer (score 2):

I see a few problems in your example.

1. Be careful naming your variables. `x` for example, is almost always a `NumericProperty` of the widget already.
2. When you reference an attribute in python, use `self`, or the widgets `x` in your case wil not change.
3. When you have a loop in kivy, you will block the application. So you either use `Clock` or `threading`. I will suggest `threading` instead of `Clock` when using serial, because `readline()` will also block the app if waiting for an input.
4. You never actually call `tm()`

So, heres what I would change in `MainWindow` class, and a few more imports.

```
import serial
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import mainthread
import threading


KV = """

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:

    Label:
        size: 75, 50
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'bottom': 1}
        background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        text: root.label_text

"""


class MainWindow(Screen):
    label_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        threading.Thread(target=self.tm).start()

    def tm(self):
        while (1):
            with serial.Serial('COM4', 9600) as ser:
                value = ser.readline()
                ser.close()
                self.update_label(value.decode("ascii").strip())

    @mainthread
    def update_label(self, value):
        self.label_text = value

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Be sure to use `mainthread` when changing any ui element in another thread. In this case when you change a stringproperty that will change the display.

Comment: thank u for the response ! but i cant the the window to pop up but the program can run

Comment: what is the KV='''  for

Comment: @Budaksesat2000 oh yea sorry. Let me make a more complete example. I have changed it, now you should be able to copy and paste and run. KV is just a string instead of a file, `Builder.load_string` is used instead then. Easier for me to make an example in one file.

Comment: Thanks bro ! However, i got an error "ValueError: MainWindow.label_text accept only str" so i change self.update_label(value) to self.update_label(str(value)) and it works ! However, the display is like this b'26.90\n'.

Comment: @Budaksesat2000 Ah yea python3. decode() and strip(). I see you already figured it out in your new question.

Comment: @Budaksesat2000 a tip for you. In python3 you only need to write `super().__init__(**kwargs)`